# SwiftUI's PreviewProvider functions is causing issues

Tags: swift, swiftui

Working with SwiftUI, I've experienced issued with the `PreviewProvider` a couple of times and haven't figured yet how to properly treat this function.

How can I prevent issues in this case, because right now, it obviously says:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'ShelterDetailedView(shelter:)'

`shelter` inside of `ShelterDetailedView` is being forwarded by the view's parent. I get this data from a database.

```
struct ShelterDetailedView: View {
    var shelter: Shelter

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                HStack {
                    Image(shelter.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
                    Image("pacific")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                DetailedViewDistance(shelter: shelter)
                Spacer()
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: -30)
            DetailedViewHeader(shelter: shelter)
            Spacer()
        }
    }

}

struct ShelterDetailedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ShelterDetailedView(shelter: ??????)
    }
}
```

```
class Shelter: Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let available: Bool
    let distance: Double
    let gender: String?

    init?(id: String, title: String, image: String, available: Bool, distance: Double, gender: String?) {

        if id.isEmpty || title.isEmpty || image.isEmpty || distance < 0 {
            return nil
        }

        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.available = available
        self.distance = distance
        self.gender = gender
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some stub instance explicitly:

```
struct ShelterDetailedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ShelterDetailedView(shelter: Shelter(... parameters here ...))
    }
}
```